# Where is the Symmetrize option under Remesh is located now?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

where is the "symmetrize" option that used to be under "Dyntopo" > "Remesh" now? I'm using 2.9, and I couldn't find it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the ► **Symmetry** section (next section in your screenshot), at the bottom there is the *Symmetrize* button. (Blender 2.91)

[image]